# How to translate this SQL query to a LINQ query in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following table :

```sql
Indicators(A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT, TimeInsertedLocal DateTime) .
```

And I have the EF Core mapping entity that maps to this table.

I need to translate this SQL query to ef core Linq equivalent query .

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D, TimeInsertedLocal
FROM Indicators
WHERE TimeInsertedLocal >= 
(   
    SELECT MAX(I.TimeInsertedLocal) 
    FROM Indicators AS I
)
```

and this is the entity :

```cs
public class Indicator
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeInsertedLocal { get; set; }
 }
```

How to write the LINQ query so that EF Core generate the same query or a better query that achieves the same result?

Comment: Where is your related entity classes?

Comment: How can a record be greater than the `MAX(TimeInsertedLocal)`?

Comment: TimeInsertedLocal  is the DateTime at which the rows was inserted.

Comment: I updated the question, it includes now the entity class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's literally one to one translation.

*SQL query*

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D , TimeInsertedLocal
FROM Indicators
WHERE TimeInsertedLocal >= 
(   
    SELECT MAX(I.TimeInsertedLocal) 
    FROM Indicators AS I
)
```

*EF Core LINQ query:*

```cs
var indicators = dbContext.Set<Indicator>();
var query = indicators
    .Where(i => i.TimeInsertedLocal >= indicators.Max(i2 => (DateTime?)i2.TimeInsertedLocal));
```

*EF Core generated SQL query:*

```sql
SELECT [i].[A], [i].[B], [i].[C], [i].[D], [i].[TimeInsertedLocal]
FROM [Indicators] AS [i]
WHERE [i].[TimeInsertedLocal] >= (
    SELECT MAX([i2].[TimeInsertedLocal])
    FROM [Indicators] AS [i2]
)
```

The only specific detail in LINQ query is the `DateTime?` cast inside `Max`, otherwise EF Core will try to emulate LINQ `Max` method throwing behavior and will evaluate query [client side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval).

Comment: Yes you nailed it. and without that cast there is two round-trips to the database server that is is weird.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are no indicators with a value of TimeInsertedLocal that is larger than the largest value of TimeInsertedLocal of all Indicators.

However, it might be that you have several indicators with a value equal to the largest value of TimeInsertedLocal.

If that is the case, you need to make groups of Indicators with the same TimeInsertedLocal, and take the group with the largest value.

```
var indicatorsWithLargestTimeInsertedLocal = myDbContext.Indicators
    // make groups of Indicators with same TimeInsertedLocal:
    .GroupBy(indicator => indicator.TimeInsertedLocal)

    // put the group with the largest TimeInsertedLocal first:
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)

    // The first group of indicators, is the group with the largest value of TimeInsertedLocal
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you are certain the TimeInsertedLocal is unique, you don't have to GroupBy, there will only be one indicator with the largest TimeInsertedLocal

```
var indicatorWithLargestTimeInsertedLocal = myDbContext.Indicators
    .OrderByDescending(indicator => indicator.TimeInsertedLocal)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This brings all the data in the table and then filter them in the app. I need this to be done in the database level.

Comment: What make you think so? If myDbContext.Indicators is`IQueryable<Indicator>`, then GroupBy, OrderByDescending and FirstOrDefault will be executed `AsQueryable`, meaning that they will be executed by the DBMS

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Currently EF Core `IQueryable` does not guarantee DBMS execution - see  [Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) and [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview). From your postings looks like you have little or no experience with EF Core. EF Core is completely different system than EF6, so you can't apply your knowledge from EF6 there.

Comment: You are right, I tried it on entity framework. Didn't pay attention that it was core