# EFCore Linq: Select only the records with the max value of a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework Core (lambda syntax). This seems like such an easy thing to do, but it is eluding me for some reason.

Lets say I have a simple table like this:

```
Run  Result
1    result1
1    result2
2    result3
2    result4
```

All I want to do is grab the rows with the max run value.

So the result should be:

```
2    result3
2    result4
```

Basically group by the Run and get the group with the max run value and return all the rows. Maybe I'm thinking about that the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by won't work (no natural SQL translation).

However some sort of self join will do.

For instance

```
db.Runs.Where(e => e.Run == db.Runs.Max(e2 => (int?)e2.Run))
```

i.e. take the records with max `Run` (see [How to translate this SQL query to a LINQ query in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815535/how-to-translate-this-sql-query-to-a-linq-query-in-ef-core/55818315#comment98324477_55818315) for why nullable cast is needed)

Or

```
db.Runs.Where(e => !db.Runs.Any(e2 => e2.Run > e.Run))
```

i.e. take records where no record with greater `Run` exists.

Comment: That worked, thanks! So simple, and makes perfect sense as well, I was just stuck on thinking group by was the way to go about this. O_o