# Evaluate EF query with MAX on the server

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-2.2

Using Entity Framework Core 2.2 I have the following query:

```
var user = await context.Users.AsNoTracking()
  .Include(x => x.Lessons).ThenInclude(x => x.LessonLevel)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);

var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking();
  .Where(x => x.LessonLevelId < user.Lessons.Max(y => y.LessonLevelId));
```

Thus query evaluates locally and I get the message:

```
The LINQ expression 'Max()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'
```

How can I make this query evaluate on the server?

**Update**

Based on DavigG answer I made it work using:

```
var maxLessonLevelId = user.Lessons.Max(y => y.LessonLevelId););

var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking();
  .Where(x => x.LessonLevelId < maxLessonLevelId);
```

I know the following evaluates locally but shouldn't evaluate on the server?

```
var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking();
  .Where(x => x.LessonLevelId < 
    context.Users.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(y => y.Id == userId)
      .Select(y => y.Lessons.Max(z => z.LessonLevelId))
      .FirstOrDefault());
```

Is it possible to use a child queries that evaluates on the server?

Comment: You could get the max value as a separate query (i.e. `var maxLessonLevelId = user.Lessons.Max(y => y.LessonLevelId);`)

Comment: I am not sure I understood your answer ... I want to get all lessons which LessonLevelId is less than the Maximum LessonLevelId of all user Lessons.

Comment: Yes, you would then use `maxLessonLevelId` instead of `user.Lessons.Max(y => y.LessonLevelId)` in your second query.

Comment: Currently you have 2 queries. Do you really need `user` instance (for something else) or it is just for the second query?

Comment: @IvanStoev I need User because I am filtering lessons with other user properties not just using user lessons. For exemple, o use User country to make additional filters.

Comment: @DavidG I just added an update with your suggestion and a question. Is it possible to use a child query that evaluates on the server? Just wondering ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura It's possible, but that's a different question. And  the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815535/how-to-translate-this-sql-query-to-a-linq-query-in-ef-core/55818315#comment98324477_55818315. Shortly, you should use nullable overload of `Max`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! That solved it without the need for defining maxLessonLevelId. I will check which one is the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the max value as a separate query, for example:

```
var maxLessonLevelId = user.Lessons.Max(y => y.LessonLevelId);
```

Then you can can get the lessons like this:

```
var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking()
                     .Where(x => x.LessonLevelId < maxLessonLevelId);
```

Comment: A side question: is there any way to use a child query that evaluates on the server as I did on my update? I know the one I posted does not. Just curious ...